# Maximum/Maximal set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology, definition

### Maximum or maximal set with property $P$

When I was reading some textbooks,
I noticed that I do not get the meaning
of the following two phrases.

($P1$) $\quad$ maximum set with property $P$

($P2$) $\quad$ maximal set with property $P$

In this regard, I have the following two questions.

($Q1$) $\quad$ Are the phrases equivalent?

($Q2$) $\quad$ What are their meanings?
(generally accepted meanings, meanings specific to particular theories)

---

As for ($Q2$), I suspect the following three meanings.

$\quad$ A set is a $\textit{maxim... set with property}$ $P$
if and only if there is $\dots$

($M1$) $\quad \dots$
no proper superset with property $P$.

($M2$) $\quad \dots$
no set with property $P$ that has greater cardinality.

($M3$) $\quad \dots$
no other set with property $P$ that has greater or equal cardinality.

---

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $(A,\leq)$ is a partial order, then we define these two definitions for $a\in A$:

- $a$ is *maximal* if whenever $a\leq b$, then $a=b$.
- $a$ is *maximum* if for every $b\in A$, $b\leq a$.

You can prove that every maximum is maximal, but a maximal element need not be a maximum. In particular there can be many maximal elements. So being maximal and maximum are not the same thing *in general*.

Now you can consider the collection $A=\{X\mid X\text{ has property }P\}$, and $\leq$ as set inclusion. Then a maximal set with property $P$ is just a maximal element of this partial order; and a maximum is a maximum in this partial order. If those even exist, of course.

Comment: With the subtelty that, sometimes, if $(A, \leq)$ already has a greatest element $\top$, maximality may mean maximality in $A \setminus \{ \top \}$ (see e.g. the notion of maximal ideal of a ring).

Comment: @Paul: No, with the subtlety that $P$ may exclude $\top$ in the first place.

Comment: Asaf: What do you mean? If $A$ is a ring then $A$ is an ideal of $A$, and the definition given e.g. by Wikipedia of a maximal ideal is "an ideal that is maximal (with respect to set inclusion) amongst all proper ideals".

Comment: @Paul: Yes. And therefore a maximal ideal is a maximal element of the partial order of *proper* ideals, thus excluding $A$ itself from having the very property required to enter the partial order in the first place.

Comment: Asaf: Yes, I think we agree. In a nutshell my point was just to recall that we don't say "maximal proper ideal" but only "maximal ideal", which could literally be understood as a maximal element in the set of all ideals.

Comment: @Paul: And we can understand the term "Random real" literally as just an arbitrary real, and not as a particular type of generic real in the context of forcing using Borel sets (basing the notion on random variables, hence the name). This can cause confusion with what is really going on. Or we can understand "large cardinals" as literally cardinals which are very large, say larger than the continuum; and not as the term should be understood, as a particular umbrella term for a family of axioms and principles in set theory. Yes, we can take a lot of things literally. We shouldn't, though.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: So it may happen that two maximal sets are of different cardinality?

Comment: @Draco: Yes, it can be. Consider the power set of $\{0,1\}$ ordered by inclusion, and consider the property $P$ being an antichain in $\mathcal P(\{0,1\})$. Then there are maximal antichains of size $1$, e.g. $\{\varnothing\}$ and there are maximal antichains of size $2$, e.g. $\{\{1\},\{2\}\}$.